# How to deal with GCP WordPress error "This page isn’t working example.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform

At first the site was working pity fine i installed "WordPress all in one migration Plugin" and migrated my movies wordpress website to the domain am hosting at "Google Cloud Platform".
Till here every thing was working fine, but when a post was clicked it redirected to an empety page saying "The page not found".
I started exploring different things within "WordPress Edittor" option from Wordpress Dashboard but nothing worked, and after a day site was completely down.
**The error am having is as follow:**
This page isn’t working watchlatestmovie.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 How to get out of it?

Comment: post nginx/php logs this error could be anything

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution, it was a file permission error in apache2.conf
Here is the solution: execute the following command in command line

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

1. Press "insert" to get into editing mode
2. Scroll down
3. Change /var/www/ Permissions from "None" to "All"
4. Press "Esc"
5. write ":qw" to exit the file.
6. Now restart the apache2 server with following command

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```