# https://srv-board./login/?redirect_to=http://srv-board/

Tags: wordpress, apache, lamp

can anybody tell me how I can rid off the redirect loop.

I found this, but didn't help:
[The requested URL /about was not found on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149418/the-requested-url-about-was-not-found-on-this-server)

The Server is a LAMP Stack with WordPress installed.

Because I am pretty new to LAMP and WordPress, let me know if you need further infos, I will provide them.

Comment: I wanted to mention, that infinite redirect goes away when I deactivate all wp-plugins

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Stackoverflow.  This question needs more details so that someone can actually help you.  You should consider reading [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Sorry for the inappropriate question. Eventually the solution is due to a misconfigured plugin in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I got the site running again by disabling the plugins. Simply renamed the plugin folder under wp-content to plugins_backup, and it worked.
So you can say that the redirect occurred because of some faulty plugin.